# Dropzone upload images and serialized all images in one data to be saved

Tags: php, mysql, serialization, image-uploading, dropzone.js

This is my function of inserting the images using dropzone but everytime I upload image it will insert a new id again it means new row..what I want is to upload all images in one row only and serialize all images.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_FILES)){

    include 'connection.php';

    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $targetDir = "uploads/";
    $fileName = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $img = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $img_name = $id . "_" . uniqid() . "_" . ($_POST['default_pic'] == $img ? "1" : "0") . "." . $fileName;
    $targetFile = $targetDir.basename($img_name);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],$targetFile)){

        $new_data = array("cover" => ($_POST['default_pic'] == $img ? "1" : "0"), "img" => $img_name); 
        $new_array[] = $new_data;

        $data_serialize = serialize($new_array);
        //insert file information into db table
        $conn->query("INSERT INTO files (file_name, uploaded) VALUES('".$data_serialize."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')");

    }

}
?>
```

the use of my array there is to customize the name of image..and put them in one variable via functions serialize.

```
$new_data = array("cover" => ($_POST['default_pic'] == $img ? "1" : "0"), "img" => $img_name); 
$new_array[] = $new_data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Dropzone allows you to set "uploadMultiple" parameter.

http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-uploadMultiple

When this is used, Dropzone will send all files in a single HTTP request, and you need to handle them on the backend side (PHP in your case). You should be able to see the format if you `var_dump` your `$_FILES`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#dz", {
            uploadMultiple: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

and of course the HTML ...

```
<form id="dz"
```